# Arrays and using the array as a index

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

Usually in c++, when traversing through an array you would count up and use the index. However, I am wondering why using the array as an index works as well.
For example,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[] = {5,7,3,2,0};
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
        cout<<i[a]<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be the same as using a[i]. Why is this?

Comment: for builtin types, `X[Y]` means `*(X+Y)` , and `+` is commutative

Answer (score -1):

In C++, the [] operator really amount to address addition.

So when you write:
a[i]

the compiler sees:
*(a + i)

And conversely, when you write i[a], the compiler sees: *(i + a).

Comment: No, an array is not a pointer.

Comment: It's a pointer to its first element.

Comment: [I'll just leave this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810668)

Comment: @PiotrTrochim No it's not.

Comment: No, an array is not a pointer. So it cannot be a pointer to the first element.

Comment: An array can *decay* to a pointer to the first element when passed over certain boundaries. But by itself, it's still an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Let me rephrase that then - the mental shortcut was too great. When one creates a C-style array (say int a[5]), then the following happens: a stack allocation of size {5 * sizeof(int)}  is made, and the address to it's start is assigned to variable 'a'. Therefore - the variable 'a' becomes a pointer to the allocated area. And of course, you can do the following assignment: int* b = a; - no need for deriving the address using the '&' operator.

Comment: Still wrong. Try `sizeof(a)` vs `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: My bad, and thank's for a valuable read. I must admit to always having thought of raw arrays as ... well, what I described. Thanks !